# Strange behavior of VS2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

Recently I was bothering by a crash of my program in release mode while runs fine under debug mode.

By inspecting deeply into my code I found that I forget to `return true` at the end of a function, which causes the crash. The function should return false when fail, otherwise, it returns true.

I am wandering whether this is a defect of the compiler(vs 2013) as it (maybe) added for me the `return true` statement at the end of the function, however it did not when releasing. Consequently, the programmer will spent lots of time in debugging the fault, although, the programmer should blame.

:)

Comment: Warning level too low for release build and/or blatantly ignoring warnings?

Comment: It's undefined behavior, the compiler can do whatever it wants to in either mode. There's probably a warning for it somewhere.

Comment: Yeah, there are indeed some warnings there. But I ignored them :(

Comment: You've just learned a valuable lesson.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flowing off the end of a function that is supposed to return a value is undefined behavior. Undefined behavior means the compiler can do anything and still be compliant. Giving a warning message is compliant. Not giving a warning message is compliant. Erasing your hard drive: That's also compliant. Fortunately for me, that hasn't happened yet. I've had the misfortune of invoking undefined behavior many, many times.

One reason this is undefined behavior is because there are some weird cases where flow analysis can't decide whether a function returns a value. Another reason is that you might have used assembly to set the return value in a way that works just fine on your computer. A third reason is that the compiler has to do flow analysis to make this determination; this is something many compilers don't do unless optimization is enabled.

That said, a lack of a return before the close brace will often trigger a compiler to check whether the function returns a value. The compiler was being nice to you when it issued a warning.

That you received a warning message and ignored it  -- Never do that. Compile with flags set to a reasonably high level and address each and every warning. Code should always compile clean. Always.

Answer (score 0):

C and C++ are tolerant languages. When the programmer writes code that the compiler can compile even if it looks *weird*, the compiler emits a warning. The warning means *you are writing something that may contain an error, but **you** take the decision*.

It allows to voluntarily do certain optimisations. For example, you can always use an 2D array as an 1D array what could not be done in some other languages. But the counterpart is **never ignore a warning if you are not sure you know why you are forcing the compiler to to something it does not like**

Conclusion : as soon as he has ignored a warning that at the end leads to the error, **the programmer** is to blame ;-)